# react-navigation calls whole stack when moving to other screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have implemented [react-navigation with redux](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html) as given in the official documentation. It is working fine but when i am moving from 1st screen to 2nd screen, it is refreshing whole stack.

I had 3 screens called LoginScreen, HomeScreen and HomeDetailScreen.

Here is the output in each case

Initial load
**output** : calls constructor of LoginScreen

When i move from Login to Home
**output** : calls constructor of LoginScren -> calls constructor of HomeScreen.

when i move from Home to HomeDetail
**output** : calls constructor of LoginScren -> calls constructor of HomeScreen -> calls constructor of HomeDetailScreen.

Version

```
react-navigation : "^2.12.1"
react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.5"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, actually issue was with `connect()`, i was doing it twice and that was the issue.

```
function ReduxNavigation() {
    const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxifyNavigator(AppNavigation, "root"));
    return (        
        <AppWithNavigationState />
    )
}
//export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ReduxNavigation)
export default ReduxNavigation
```

As you can see in above code i have already binded navigation but still i was doing the same thing while exporting it. I have commented that part of code for other users understanding.